# convert 8-digit number to date type in mysql

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table in, MySQL 5.5, having an INT column which is actually a 8-digit number representing a date value in the format `YYYYMMDD`

How can I convert this column into a DATE type so as for easy compare with other DATE column in other table?

Comment: please post inserted value

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Use mysql **STR_TO_DATE**

The **STR_TO_DATE()** converts the str string into a date value based on the fmt format string.

```
SELECT STR_TO_DATE('20141012','%Y%m%d') FROM `table`
```

Comment: Actually, the column is an INT column have many 8-digit numbers, not strings.

Comment: No problem pls try this mysql query like that STR_TO_DATE(col_name,col date format) @AlvinSIU

Comment: **STR_TO_DATE** working fine with INT data type @AlvinSIU